# Getting spring security ACL look ups to use a mysql read replica

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-security

While debugging and testing a MySql read replicate with my Spring app I notice that queries to get ACLs are hitting my master and not slave db.  I'm using the `jdbc:mysql:replication://` connection string.  This seems to be working with call that are wrapped in `@Transactional(readOnly = true)` for non ACL data.

I'm setting up my LookupStrategy via the BasicLookupStrategy using the same datasource as my JPA config.

It's as if the LookupStrategy isn't marking the connection as read-only.

Is this normal? Is there any way to change this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after reading through all the source for [BasicLookupStrategy](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/apidocs/org/springframework/security/acls/jdbc/BasicLookupStrategy.html) I didn't see anywhere where it was being done, or could be done.  Then on top of it, BasicLookupStrategy has jdbcTemplate as private making it not extendable. ug.. So ended up just coping the whole class calling it `BasicReadOnlyLookupStrategy` and added the following method `setConnectionReadOnly`' it's called before and after the call to `jdbcTemplate.query` in `lookupPrimaryKeys` and `lookupObjectIdentities`

```
private void setConnectionReadOnly(boolean readOnly) {
    log.debug("setting JDBC connection to {}", readOnly);
    try {
        Connection con = DataSourceUtils.getConnection(jdbcTemplate.getDataSource());
        con.setReadOnly(readOnly);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring Security 3.0 provides a BasicLookupStrategy class that in its constructor allows to inject the DataSource that would be used to hitting the database. So my suggestion is to use that Implementation, and also implement a ACLCache to avoid unnecessary database access.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/apidocs/org/springframework/security/acls/jdbc/BasicLookupStrategy.html